# integrality of a Riccati-type equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems

The following is a problem we were unable to prove and left stated in the paper
"Arithmetical properties of a sequence arising from an arctangent sum", J. Numb. Theory 128 (2008) 1807–1846.

Define the sequence $\{x_n\}$ by $x_1=1$ and for $n\geq2$ by
$$x_n=\frac{x_{n-1}+n}{1-nx_{n-1}}.$$
We believe and claim that $x_n$ is not an integer, for $n\geq5$. Any ideas?

**Note:** $x_1=1, x_2=-3, x_3=0, x_4=4$. Among other things, we proved $x_n\neq0$ for $n\geq4$.

**Special case:** Since the problem is a bit hard and in view of no success being reported, I propose the following special case to attend to:
prove (or disprove, which I doubt) that 
$$x_n\neq 1 \qquad \text{for any $n\geq2$}.$$

Comment: Some trivialities: So if one proves that for integers larger than four $x_n$ is non-integer, then that yields the statement in "... then $x_n\not= 0$" statement.

Comment: Oh, yes. It becomes a corollary.

Comment: For the special case,suppose there exists $n_0 \ge 2$ s.t. $x_{n_0}=1$ then $x_{n_0-1}=(1-n_0)/(1+n_0)$; now you need to find an equation for $x_{n_0-k}$ by iterating the recursive relation. Then you need to find for which values $x_{n_0-k} = x_1=1$, and then search for a contradiction. BTW, the denominator of your recursive relation should be well defined, i.e. it's not defined for: $x_n = 1/(n+1)$.

Comment: In the above-mentioned paper, it is proved that $1-nx_{n-1}\neq0$ for $n>1$. So, $x_n$ is well-defined, no worries.

Comment: (Title: maybe you mean *Riccati*?)

Comment: Let $z_n = \prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+ik) $. Then $x_n = \frac{\Im(z_n)}{\Re(z_n)}$. Would that help?

Comment: @VictorZurkowski: That's a good suggestion. However, we exploited this interpretation to prove among other things "$x_n\neq0$ for $n\geq4$". It did not help as much for the above-stated problem. See http://129.81.170.14/~vhm/papers_html/atan-long.pdf

Comment: $x_n$ is the image of $x_{n-1}$ under the linear fractional transformation $A_n$ corresponding to $\frac{1+ni}{\sqrt{1+n^2}}\in S^1$, and so to say that $x_N = 1$ is to say that $\prod_{2\leq n\leq N} A_n$ fixes $1$. The matrices in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ that fix $1$ are of the form $\left(\begin{array}{cc} a^{-1} - z & a - a^{-1} + z \\ -z & a + z\end{array}\right)$, and the intersection of that set with $SO(2)$ is $\pm 1$. Alternatively, straight from VictorZurkowski's comment, $\Re{z_n} = \Im{z_n}$ if and only if $\frac{z_n}{1+i}\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thus we find that $\prod_{2\leq n\leq N} A_n$ is the identity, i.e. that $\prod_{2\leq n\leq N} (1+ni)\in \mathbb{Z}$. On taking norms this implies that $\prod_{2\leq n\leq N} (n^2 + 1)$ is a square, and then you can just use the same argument as Cilleruelo: the only primes dividing this guy are $\leq 2N$ and $\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, and each such prime contributes barely more than it does to $N!^2$. The lacking contributions from $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ vastly dominate, and so were the expression a square it would be less than $N!^2$ for all but potentially small $N$, a contradiction.

Comment: It seems that if you could prove that $|x_n|\ll n!^{\frac{1}{2}} \delta^n$ for sufficiently small $\delta$, then you'd have the claim. Indeed, if $x_n = a\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $|a|\ll n!^{\frac{1}{2}} \delta^n$, then $z_n := \prod_{1\leq k\leq n} (1+ki) = (1+ai)\cdot \Re(z_n)$. Taking norms it follows that $\prod_{1\leq k\leq n} (k^2+1) = (a^2 + 1)(\Re(z_n))^2$. Now on the one hand $|\Re(z_n)|\gg \frac{n!^2}{a^2 + 1}\gg n! \delta^{-2n}$.

Comment: On the other hand, again if $p^2$ divides the right-hand side $p$ must be $1\pmod{4}$ and $p\leq 2n$, so that the analysis in Cilleruelo still works and gives that the left-hand side is $\leq n! \cdot O(1)^n$. This is a contradiction for $n$ large (once $\delta\ll 1$), leaving a finite number of $n$ to check.

(Let me know if anything above is nonsense! It's gotten a bit late here.)